# If statement not separating Albums

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If statement does not separate between Albums from List.  When ran it all prints Yes and when I used not equal all printed no. Why is it not checking to see if the Album is NT and print Yes and all others print No?

```
    nt = 0
    ft = 0

    for alb in range(len(albm)):
                    
        while nt < len(newtracks):
            while ft < len(filezto):

                if albm[alb]  == 'NT' and newtracks[nt] == filezto[ft] :
                   
                        print('Yes', newtracks[nt] ,' ft', filezto[ft])

                else:
                        print('No', newtracks[nt], 'ft',filezto[ft])
                nt = nt +1
                ft = ft +1
```

Comment: what is the relevance of newtracks ? what does newtracks and filezto have to do with albm[alb]

Comment: assume albm is a dictionary and you want to find out if `NT` is in albm dictionary? if so, you can iterate thru albm.values() and see if it has NT

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions, realizing that because of the lack of the input data in your question, this may not be your final answer:

1. Instead of iterating on a range, try doing `for album in albm`, in that case, if each `album` is string, you can clearly check if any of the `item`s in the loop get set to `NT` value.
2. Same goes for `newtracks` and `filezto` (assuming that you are trying to do a cross join between the two sets), I would simply change your code to:

```
    albums = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'NT', 'X']
    new_tracks = [10,11,12,13,14,15]
    fileztos = [100,11,120,130,14,150]
    
    for album in albums:
        for new_track, filezto in ((n, f) for n in new_tracks for f in fileztos):
    
            if album == 'NT' and new_track == filezto:
    
                print('Yes', new_track, ' ft', filezto)
    
            else:
                print('No', new_track, ' ft', filezto)
```

Should produce the following outcome:

```
No 10  ft 100
No 10  ft 11
No 10  ft 120
No 10  ft 130
No 10  ft 14
No 10  ft 150
No 11  ft 100
No 11  ft 11
No 11  ft 120
No 11  ft 130
No 11  ft 14
No 11  ft 150
No 12  ft 100
No 12  ft 11
No 12  ft 120
No 12  ft 130
No 12  ft 14
No 12  ft 150
No 13  ft 100
No 13  ft 11
No 13  ft 120
No 13  ft 130
No 13  ft 14
No 13  ft 150
No 14  ft 100
No 14  ft 11
No 14  ft 120
No 14  ft 130
No 14  ft 14
No 14  ft 150
No 15  ft 100
No 15  ft 11
No 15  ft 120
No 15  ft 130
No 15  ft 14
No 15  ft 150
No 10  ft 100
No 10  ft 11
No 10  ft 120
No 10  ft 130
No 10  ft 14
No 10  ft 150
No 11  ft 100
No 11  ft 11
No 11  ft 120
No 11  ft 130
No 11  ft 14
No 11  ft 150
No 12  ft 100
No 12  ft 11
No 12  ft 120
No 12  ft 130
No 12  ft 14
No 12  ft 150
No 13  ft 100
No 13  ft 11
No 13  ft 120
No 13  ft 130
No 13  ft 14
No 13  ft 150
No 14  ft 100
No 14  ft 11
No 14  ft 120
No 14  ft 130
No 14  ft 14
No 14  ft 150
No 15  ft 100
No 15  ft 11
No 15  ft 120
No 15  ft 130
No 15  ft 14
No 15  ft 150
No 10  ft 100
No 10  ft 11
No 10  ft 120
No 10  ft 130
No 10  ft 14
No 10  ft 150
No 11  ft 100
No 11  ft 11
No 11  ft 120
No 11  ft 130
No 11  ft 14
No 11  ft 150
No 12  ft 100
No 12  ft 11
No 12  ft 120
No 12  ft 130
No 12  ft 14
No 12  ft 150
No 13  ft 100
No 13  ft 11
No 13  ft 120
No 13  ft 130
No 13  ft 14
No 13  ft 150
No 14  ft 100
No 14  ft 11
No 14  ft 120
No 14  ft 130
No 14  ft 14
No 14  ft 150
No 15  ft 100
No 15  ft 11
No 15  ft 120
No 15  ft 130
No 15  ft 14
No 15  ft 150
No 10  ft 100
No 10  ft 11
No 10  ft 120
No 10  ft 130
No 10  ft 14
No 10  ft 150
No 11  ft 100
**Yes 11  ft 11**
No 11  ft 120
No 11  ft 130
No 11  ft 14
No 11  ft 150
No 12  ft 100
No 12  ft 11
No 12  ft 120
No 12  ft 130
No 12  ft 14
No 12  ft 150
No 13  ft 100
No 13  ft 11
No 13  ft 120
No 13  ft 130
No 13  ft 14
No 13  ft 150
No 14  ft 100
No 14  ft 11
No 14  ft 120
No 14  ft 130
**Yes 14  ft 14**
No 14  ft 150
No 15  ft 100
No 15  ft 11
No 15  ft 120
No 15  ft 130
No 15  ft 14
No 15  ft 150
No 10  ft 100
No 10  ft 11
No 10  ft 120
No 10  ft 130
No 10  ft 14
No 10  ft 150
No 11  ft 100
No 11  ft 11
No 11  ft 120
No 11  ft 130
No 11  ft 14
No 11  ft 150
No 12  ft 100
No 12  ft 11
No 12  ft 120
No 12  ft 130
No 12  ft 14
No 12  ft 150
No 13  ft 100
No 13  ft 11
No 13  ft 120
No 13  ft 130
No 13  ft 14
No 13  ft 150
No 14  ft 100
No 14  ft 11
No 14  ft 120
No 14  ft 130
No 14  ft 14
No 14  ft 150
No 15  ft 100
No 15  ft 11
No 15  ft 120
No 15  ft 130
No 15  ft 14
No 15  ft 150

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've made few assumptions I must point out - that `albums` is an array of `str` and `newtracks`, `filezto` for comparison purpose, are all integers. You may need to change the conditions slightly to match the code to your data.

Comment: newtracks = List of updated file names from folder, filezto = List that was used to update files which is list newtracks. Album=List of Albums(OT and NT Only).  With the exception of the list newtracks all were taken from a spreadsheet.  What I am seeking to accomplish is to have it compare the files(newtracks) and (filezto) and check if the album is NT and if so print Yes else print No. The other last piece of the puzzle is to move those files that match to selected folders based upon a list from the spreadsheet . for ex file 01 Gen00 album: NT move to folder 1-GEN Gene.